# Hibernate Warning about PersistenceProvider occurs even if correct provider is given

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

When I am trying to use Hibernate with a local Derby-Database, I always get a Warning about the wrong persistence provider three times:

```
[WARN] HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
[WARN] HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
[WARN] HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
```

I can't find any reason for this, because my persistence.xml (which is the only persistence.xml in the project) looks like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="performanzdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="myUrl;create=true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and therefore defines the correct persistence provider `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`.

Another reason I could imagine is that some of my maven dependencies are wrong, but these are just the most recent `entitymanager`- and `jpamodelgen-dependencies`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Besides the warning in the beginning and the error:

```
[ERROR] HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : package.class_#field
```

occurring for newly defined fields from time to time, Hibernate runs fine and everything is written in the database as it should.

Does anyone know, why the wrong `PersistenceProvider` is used or why this error occurs?

Comment: have a look [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9141)

Comment: Thanks, with the workaround of setting the persistence provider in `PersistenceProviderResolverHolder` the warning isn't shown anymore. So the error with the static metamodel field is happening because of https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8712, and is independent of the Persistence Provider?

Comment: yes can be , not much idea, just posted an answer with similar link, for your acceptance/upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar problem has been reported [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9141), please have a look.

from the above links,

```
This bug also affects version 4.3.7.Final.
```

Answer (score 0):

With a new maven-based Spring Boot project including JPA depencencies, I still see these warning log lines when slf4j level is INFO.

```
14:04:47.990 [main] WARN  o.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
14:04:47.990 [main] WARN  o.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
14:04:47.990 [main] WARN  o.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
```

I found this solution https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9141 and added a snippet of code to just before creating the entity manager factory:

```
public EntityManager create() {
    if (AbstractBaseForJUnit.EMF == null) {
        PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.setPersistenceProviderResolver(new PersistenceProviderResolver() {
            private final List<PersistenceProvider> providers_ = Arrays.asList((PersistenceProvider) new HibernatePersistenceProvider());

            @Override
            public void clearCachedProviders() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public List<PersistenceProvider> getPersistenceProviders() { 
                return providers_; 
            }
        });

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(AbstractBaseForJUnit.PU_NAME)) {
            AbstractBaseForJUnit.PU_NAME = CoreProperties.Features.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME;
        }
        AbstractBaseForJUnit.EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(AbstractBaseForJUnit.PU_NAME);
    }

    if (this.EM == null) {
        this.EM = AbstractBaseForJUnit.EMF.createEntityManager();
        this.EM.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    }

    return EM;
}
```

And also changed my persistence.xml

<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

Now no more warnings.